# In pycharm IDE i am dealing with face_recognition,PIL module but while running below code it doesn'st shows images

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library, face-recognition

**Below code does not shows images in pycharm IDE**
**It does not give any error but doesn't show the pull images**
*In group-four-business-people-row-pointing-36133535.jpg four people are in the image*

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition

image = face_recognition.load_image_file('img\group-four-business-people-row-pointing-36133535.jpg')
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

for face_location in face_locations:
    top, right, bottom, left = face_location

    face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
    pil_image.show()
```

Comment: Are you getting any coordinates in ```top, right, bottom, left```?, try printing it and check it.

Comment: Yes it print the co-ordinates for top,right,bottom,left.For example print(right) prints the 196
150
239
184